# Scan and Filters in HBase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloud, hbase, distributed-computing

I am new to HBase. Please tell me how to use Scan and Filter for querying data from HBase (A sample piece of code). Have searched a lot. But got confused. Pls help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not so difficult to find help on that. Googling for **how to use hbase filters** will definitely give you a lot of good links. See **[this](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/database-design/9781449314682/filters/id4460220)** and **[this](http://hbase.apache.org/book/client.filter.html)** for example.

AFA using **Filters** is concerned, first you need to create a **Scan** object, then create a **Filter** instance, add the filter to this scan object and call the **getScanner()** using a **HTable** instance passing **scan** object as a parameter to it. **For example**, I have a table where with some data related to my users and the rowkey is userID. Now, I want to get all the information about all the users whose userID starts with **abc**. In such a scenario I can make use of **PrefixFilter** by passing **abc** as the parameter. This will return me all the rows whose rowkey start with **abc**. Something like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    HTable table = new HTable(conf, TABLE_NAME);
    String userID = "abc";

    //Get the data
    Scan s = new Scan();
    Filter filter = new PrefixFilter(Bytes.toBytes("abc"));
    s.setFilter(filter);
    ResultScanner rs = table.getScanner(s);
    for(Result r : rs){
        System.out.println("VALUE : " + Bytes.toString(r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("c1"))));
    }
    rs.close();
    table.close();
}
```

The **Result** API provides a lot of methods which you can use as per your needs, like **getRow(), getColumn()** etc. You can have a look at the **[API](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html)** for more information. I would also suggest you to get a copy of **HBase The Definitive Guide** by **Lars George**. It's a great book with everything you will need in order to learn about HBase. For Filters see the **Chapter 4**.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the sample code for Scan and Filters:**

```
    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    HTable table = new HTable(conf, "emp");
    List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<Filter>();
    Filter famFilter = new FamilyFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
    new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("salary")));
    filters.add(famFilter);
    Filter colFilter = new QualifierFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
    new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("gross")));
    filters.add(colFilter);
    Filter valFilter = new      
    ValueFilter(CompareFilter.CompareOp.GREATER_OR_EQUAL,
    new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("1500")));
    filters.add(valFilter);
    FilterList fl = new FilterList( FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL,filters);
    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.setFilter(fl);
    ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan);
    for (Result result : scanner) {
         for (KeyValue kv : result.raw()) {
        System.out.println("kv:"+kv +", Key: " + Bytes.toString(kv.getRow())          +",Value: " +Bytes.toString(kv.getValue()));
          }
    }
    scanner.close();
```